# sum of elements in rows using 2d array

Tags: java

i am trying to print the sum of the elements per row in 2d array at the bottom and i am just a begginer and i got confuse but i dont know what to do at the bottom of my codes... please help me her's my codes:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        printArray(initializeArray());
    }
    public static int [] [] initializeArray()
    {
      int [] [] alpha = new int [4] [3];
      for(int i=0;i< alpha.length;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
              if((i+j)>=2)
                  alpha[i][j]=i*j;
                  else
                  alpha[i][j]=i+j;
      return alpha;
    }
    public static void printArray(int [][] alpha)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<alpha.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<alpha[i].length;j++)
                System.out.print(alpha [i][j]+",");
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

    public static void printSumofRow(int [] [] alpha )
    {
        write codes here that will print the sum of the elements per row.
    }   

}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard, you just need a variable to hold the sum of row elements.

```
public static void printSumofRow(int[][] alpha) {
    for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < alpha[i].length; j++) {
            sum += alpha[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of row " + (i + 1) + " = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Then in your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] alpha = initializeArray();

    printArray(alpha);
    printSumofRow(alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void printSumByRow(int [] [] a )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        sum  = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) {
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println("Row no. " + i + " is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think that what are you looking for:

```
public static void printSumofRow(int [] [] alpha )
{
    int[] results = new int[4];
    for(int i=0;i<alpha.length;i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<alpha[i].length;j++)
            sum += alpha[i][j];
        results[i] = sum;
    }

    //for checking results
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){
        System.out.println(results[i]);
    }

}
```

hope that helps.